# fgets doesn't work -

Tags: c, file-io, fgets

Suddenly fgets stoped working while i haven't done any change that will affect the function 
here is my code .please let me know why it is not working !?

```
  void readInfo()
{struct grades *grades=malloc(3*sizeof(grades));
   char line[60],str[6];
   int i=0;

   FILE *rf=fopen("Grades.txt","r");
   if(!feof(rf)&&fgets(line,60,rf)!=NULL)

   {           puts("inside if1");


         while(i<3)
         {

             sscanf(line,"%d %s %c",&(grades[i]).ID,str,&(grades[i].grade));
            strcpy(str,((*(grades+i)).course));
                        i++;
            printInfo(grades+i);puts("herwr");
         }

   }
   fclose(rf);
}
```

*********CODE EDITED

Comment: `fgets()` works — you may not be using it properly, but `fgets()` works.

Comment: Please learn an orthodox indentation and layout style. Don't put multiple statements on a single line.  Don't put multiple close braces on a single line.

Comment: `fscanf` takes the target argument `str`, but `char *str` has no memory allocated to it.

Comment: Using `fgets()` to read a line is sensible, but then using `fscanf()` inside the loop to read the next line is probably not what you intended.  That should probably be a call to `sscanf()`.  You should check the return value from whichever of the `scanf()` family you do call, to make sure everything worked.  It is clearer to use subscript notation (`&grades[i].grade`) than the alternative (`&((*(grades+i)).grade)`).

Comment: ... strangely you go on to `strcpy` something to `str` which you recently entered (and still has no memory allocated).

Comment: For the 10K users, here's the first time this was asked:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41002481/fgets-doesnt-work

Comment: Why are you checking `!feof(stdin)` instead of `!feof(rf)`? But that will always be true, because the EOF flag doesn't get set until after you try to read at the end of the file.

Comment: `&((*(grades+i)).ID)` would be more readable as `&grades[i].ID`

Comment: @WeatherVane well our teacher said we should use strcpy when we initializing a string

Comment: @WeatherVane I suspect he got the order of arguments to `strcpy()` backwards.

Comment: @ssai You use `strcpy()` to copy from one string to another. But the destination string needs memory allocated first.

Comment: In your case, you need to allocate memory for `str` so you can read into it with `fscanf()`.

Comment: Define "not working" - is your program crashing, are you getting unexpected results, what?

Comment: What makes you think `fgets()` isn't working? You never do anything with `line`.

Comment: @JohnBode well my function is not working it doesn't enter the while loop . and after tracing i knew that the reason is fgets but i'm not sure what did i written wrong .

Comment: @ssai `strcpy` only works when the target has memory allocated somehow, perhaps you misunderstood what your teacher said. It cannot initialise the unitialised *pointer* `char *str`.

Comment: @barmer yeah right I am supposed to use it with sscanf I'll edit my code . but still it doesn't work !

Comment: I'm going to say what should be rule #1 of most questions - what happens when you run this in the debugger?  The reason this s/b first? Because most people assume what the program is doing, rather than know what the program is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rewrite of your code:

<sup>*Uncompiled, much less tested.*</sup>

```
void readInfo(void)
{    
    int i = 0;
    FILE *rf = fopen("Grades.txt", "r");
    if (rf != NULL)
    {
        char line[1024];
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), rf) != NULL)
        {
            struct grades grade;
            puts("inside while");
            if (sscanf(line, "%d %s %c", &grade.ID, grade.course, &grade.grade) == 3)
            {
                i++;
                printInfo(&grade);
            }
        }
        puts("here");
        fclose(rf);
    }
    printf("%d grades accepted\n", i);
}
```

Changes include:

- Not allocating an array for grades — you never reuse the value.
- No problem with the missing `free()`.
- Testing that the file was opened.
- Not trying to close the file if it was not opened.
- Allowing for bigger lines — it is painless and avoids problems.
- Checking that the `sscanf()` was successful.
- Printing the number of grades accepted.

Other possibilities:

- Remove diagnostic prints. They're temporary, but can be useful when things aren't working as you want.
- It would be better if the file name was passed as an argument to the function.
- It would probably be better if there was an error report if the file could not be opened (and the message should include the file name), normally written to standard error.
- If you want to process up to three grade lines, you can do that.
- If you want to process an indefinite number of grade lines, you can do that.
- If you want to return the array of grades, you can do that (but how do you say how big the array is — there are multiple possibilities).

All those require some changes to the coding, though nothing very outrageously complex.